# How to discard a running HKWorkoutSession

Tags: swift, watchos, healthkit, hkworkoutsession

I'm building a companion watch app for my workout tracker app and, I would like to discard a workout session triggered on the watch when user closes a workout session on the iOS app. But it seems like there is no discard or cancel method on `HKWorkoutSession`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no discard or cancel method for `HKWorkoutSession`, we can use its associated workout builder (`HKLiveWorkoutBuilder`) to discard workout before calling `end` on the session. So, we can cancel a running `HKWorkoutSession` as follows (Add this method to your watchOS workout manager where you keep a reference to the running session):

```
func discardCurrentWorkoutSession() {
    guard let session else {
        return
    }
    let builder = session.associatedWorkoutBuilder()
    builder.discardWorkout()
    session.end()
    self.session = nil
}
```

Then the session will be discarded and no data will be saved to HealthKit.